# form-validation jquery same name with rules

Tags: jquery, validation, formvalidation-plugin

I had a problem before with regards to validating array values using jquery.
I got it to work using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// MODE 1
var numberIncr = 1;
$('#inputs').append($('<p><input class="comment required" name="name[' + 0 + ']" /></p>'));
$("#addInput").on('click', function () {
    $('#inputs').append($('<p><input class="comment required" name="name[' + numberIncr + ']" /></p>'));
    numberIncr++;
});

$('form.commentForm').validate();
});
```

The only problem I have is that when I try to insert this inside the .validate()

```
rules:{
        'name[]': "required"
    },
    messages:{
        'name[]':{
            required: "Invalid input"
        }
    }
```

The message still doesn't change. Is it possible for me to loop through the array inside the .validate function or is there another way?

EDIT:
I checked the post associated with the duplicate but I think it's different because the size of the array changes when i press the + button. My problem is setting a message for everything inside the array name

Comment: You name is NOT name[] it is name[0]

Comment: my bad, but how do i go about the rest of the array? like lets say name [1] -[4]?

Comment: Perhaps `"input[name^='name']"`

Comment: tried it but it's still not working. i really need help